# Excel formula to populate cell with list of texts not found in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Apologies, I could not make the title more descriptive :)

I would like to achieve this without using VBA

**Scenario I am trying to achieve**:

1. I have a column with data with comma separated values like below

[image]

2. I have another list of data with all possible values as below

[image]

3. I would like to get output as below. Compare the list and populate what is missing in second column

[image]

Comment: Just a tip - you may also get useful help with this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Lookup Delimited Data

[image]

```
=LET(sData,A2:A7,dData,C2:C4,dlm,", ",
BYROW(dData,LAMBDA(r,TEXTJOIN(dlm,,
    FILTER(sData,ISERROR(XMATCH(sData,TEXTSPLIT(r,,dlm))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd> function :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=MAP(C1:C4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A1:A6,ISERROR(SEARCH(", "&A1:A6&", ",", "&x&", "))))))
```

---